# Definition cluster point for function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, terminology

I found this definition for cluster point property but I am not sure if this is related somehow to the definition of the function that has cluster points at  specific point
or they are separate concepts.
Here is the definition :
we say the function $h:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$  has a cluster point  property there are sequences $a_n\to-\infty$ and $b_n\to\infty$ such that $h(a_n)\to 0$ and $h(b_n)\to 0.$

**Edit** Let $g\colon \Bbb (2,3) \to \Bbb R$ be a homeomoerphism. assume $h$ with  cluster point property as defined above. Does this ensure $h\circ g$ will have cluster at endpoints, that is, at $1$ and $2$?

Comment: I have never seen this definition before. Unless the function is also assumed to be continuous, this says very little about it.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, Thank you very much. If $h$ is continuous what we say about it ? Also, I edited the question. Does that ensure any thing about composition $h\circ g$?

Comment: If $h$ is continuous, it says that $\lim_{x\to\infty}h(x)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}h(x)=0$, and then you’ll have $$\lim_{x\to 2^+}(h\circ g)(x)=0=\lim_{x\to 3^-}(h\circ g)(x)\,.$$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, but this does not tell us any thing about cluster point at endpoints right

Comment: It says that the values of $(h\circ g)(x)$ are clustering at $0$ at each end of the interval $(2,3)$.

Comment: Brain M. Scott. Could you pleas clear this point ? It seems I missed something

Comment: I’m not sure exactly what it is that you’re not understanding. Possibly we mean different things by *clustering*, but I would say that the values of $(h\circ g)(x)$ are clustering at $0$ at both ends of the interval.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, One more thing related to this. Assume $h$ as define in OP with property and let $h$ satisfies the intermediate value theorem instated of continuity . $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)=0$

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, By the way, you said if $h$ is continuous , together cluster point property as stated in OP, then we have $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)=0$. I think this is not correct since take $h(x)=sinx$ and $a_n=\pi\times n$ so $h(x)=sinx$ satisfies the property and continuous but $\lim_{x\to\infty} h(x)$ does not exist